# PowerShell 5.1 Why doesn't my sql output occur within the method

Tags: powershell

Sql output works in main as expected, but not in the DoWork function. Why?

```
function Main {
    $result = DoWork
    $result | Format-Table -AutoSize
}

function DoWork {
    #return results without assigning to variable
    
    $result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select top 1 * from customer" -ServerInstance "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" -Database "Database1" -OutputAs DataTables
    #$result | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
```

Main

[image]

Comment: ```Format-Table``` doesn’t write to the console by itself - it just formats an object into “meta formatting” objects. You need to pipe it into ```out-host``` to render it in the console. Your ```DoWork``` is sending the formatting objects into the output pipeline from ```DoWork``` and they’re being captured into the ```$result``` variable in ```Main’``

Comment: By contrast, the output from```Main``` is being returned to the top-level scope and is getting automatically sent to ```out-host``` and shown in the console.

Comment: @mclayton sounds like a proper answer ;)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - I’m stuck posting from my phone and can’t test any code so didn’t want to write an answer with typos. Feel free to write one, or I’ll check back when I’m at a PC :-)

Comment: @mclayton can you make that an answer and I'll give you creds.

Comment: I noticed that putting `Write-Host` in front of the sql results behaves differently, can you explain that in answer as added related insight

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the comments...

**Background**

`Format-Table` and `Format-List` don't actually write to the console themselves - they just convert an object into "meta formatting" objects. You need to pipe these into `out-host` to render output to the console:

You can, in fact, also just pipe the original value to `out-host` as well, but you'll get the default formatting without any customisations you might want to specify in `Format-Table` or `Format-List`:

[Out-Host - Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host?view=powershell-7.2#notes)

> The cmdlets that contain the Out verb, Out-, don't format objects. They render objects and send them to the specified display destination. If you send an unformatted object to an Out- cmdlet, the cmdlet sends it to a formatting cmdlet before rendering it.

You can see this if you try the following:

```
PS> $x = @( "aaa", "bbb" ) | format-table

PS> $x | foreach-object { $_.GetType().FullName }
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData

PS> $x | out-host
aaa
bbb
```

You might also note this:

```
PS> $x
aaa
bbb
```

But that's because the top level scope (including the interactive prompt) is special - any uncaptured objects returned to the top level scope will be automatically passed to `Out-Host` to be formatted and displayed in the host (i.e. the console):

[Out-Host - Description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host?view=powershell-7.2#description)

> Out-Host is automatically appended to every command that is executed. It passes the output of the pipeline to the host executing the command.

**Answer**

In your script, `$result | Format-Table -AutoSize` in your `DoWork` function is converting `$result` into formatting objects and sending them into the output pipeline from `DoWork` and they’re being captured into the `$result` variable in `Main`, never to find their way to the console.

By contrast, the output from `$result | Format-Table -AutoSize` in `Main` is being returned to the top-level scope and is getting automatically sent to `out-host`, and then rendered to the console.

If you want `DoWork` to write output to the console you can do this instead `$result | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-Host` or, my personally preferred approach `Write-Host ($result | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String)` as it's easier to scan the code for `Write-Host` on the left of the line rather than `| Out-Host` on the right, but that's a stylistic choice...